# How does linux store the last command used?

Tags: shell

I need to know how does linux store the used command. I try to seek some file. But I can not find anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is located in `~/.bash_history`

Comment: Only if you're using bash though... And if that is what the `$HISTFILE` variable is set to.